# Dynamic PlacementTarget for a user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So i built a user control with his relative view model. This control must be shown when a button is clicked inside a `ComboBox`. To give you a better idea i'll post my code:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="7,0,10,0">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding CBSource}" />
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding FirstProperty}"/>
                    <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SecondProperty}"/>
                    <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding ThirdProperty}"/>
                    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Width="140" Visibility="{Binding HasCombobox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                            <CompositeCollection>
                                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" />
                                <ComboBoxItem>
                                    <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Content="{x:Static prop:Resources.INSERT_BTN}" Command ="This will call CustomUserControl"></Button>
                                </ComboBoxItem>
                            </CompositeCollection>
                        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    </ComboBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

This is the template of my `ItemsControl`. This control show a `ComboBox` whenever a property is verified. So in my view, i have no idea of how many `ComboBox` i will have and where those will be placed (the combination of all this `ItemsControl` create a sort of grid). My goal is to show a little view with a variable placement target (it must pop near the `ComboBox` that called it).

Requirements : I need a way to place my `CustomUserControl.xaml` inside the `ItemControl` that i described above, with a dynamic placement target. The button that will call this control, will have an `ICommand` dedicated to execute the routine to set and show the CustomUserControl

Comment: Do you want to show `Popup` with `CustomUserControl` placed near `ComboBox`?

Comment: @Maxim i did never worked with `Popup` so i don't know if it's suitable for my case. I only know that `CustomUserControl` is a view with his view model that must be shown near the combobox who called it

Comment: @Maxim Plus, my question is, with popup, can i generate the content everytime the property IsOpened = true? Because CustomUserControl is a view with different content based on which combobox button launch the command

Comment: Where does the the dynamic content come from?

Comment: @mm8 the "dynamic content" is a view that can be placed as a content of a control in this way :  <view:CustomUserControl /> . It will be generated by one of the button (each one in a different combobox) using a Command

Comment: Where is the command defined...?

Comment: @DanieleSartori Yes you can set `Child` property of `Popup` in runtime.

Comment: the code of the command is definend in the view model of the window that contain the ItemControl described in the main post. The command property is defined inside the button

Comment: So the view model creates the actual view...? This is clearly wrong.

Comment: @mm8 in my plan the view model will launch the command that will show the view. The command must recognise which button was clicked and based on this will set the view in the proper way. If this is wrong, i can do the same thing using the click event. I didn't implemented yet, my actual problem is to know how i can show this view in different position of my UI

Comment: Please refer to my answer. It should hopefully give you the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit unclear but you could use a `Popup` element and binds its `PlacementTarget` to element relative to which the `Popup` is positioned when it opens: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.placementtarget(v=vs.110).aspx

You can then use the `ContentControl` in the `Popup` and bind its `Content` property to a property that returns a view model (or a UserControl) that defines the contents to be dislayed in the Popup. Something like this:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="Button" />
<Popup IsOpen="True" StaysOpen="True"
       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn}" 
       Placement="Top">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="100" Height="100">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding TheControlProperty}" />
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Comment: Can be the content of the popup directly a view ?

Comment: TheControlProperty is supposed to return a view if you want this to be dynamic. Obviously you cannot hardcode a view in your XAML markup if you want to be able update it dynamically.

Comment: Perfect. This is then what i needed.

Comment: Do you know why, if i click in any point of the popup this disappear?

Comment: Please ask another question if you have another issue.